# How do you use a python variable in popen()?

Tags: python, docker, popen

Im trying to record docker stats for every file in the `mydata` directory. For example if one of the files is names `piano.txt` I would like the output file to be `piano_stuff.txt`.  This is what I have so far:

```
import subprocess
import signal
import os 

for file_name in os.listdir('mydata'):
    data_txt = "./" + file_name.split(".")[0] + "_stuff.txt"
    dockerStats = subprocess.Popen("docker stats  --format {{.MemUsage}} >> ${data_txt}", shell=True)
    os.killpg(os.getpgid(dockerStats.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
```

Comment: The question is not clear. What I can probably grab is that you want the first argument of `Popen` to be a string based on the variable?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: One option is to use string formatting, like [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) or [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Comment: No, he should not be using string formatting to construct a shell command.

Comment: The question is how to include the value of `data_txt` in the shell command being constructed.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `shell=True`. Open the file locally, and pass the file object as the `stdout` argument. You can also use the `--no-stream` option to have the command exit after producing one line of output, rather than asynchronously trying to kill the process as soon as possible. (You might get multiple lines of output, or you might get none, depending on when the OS schedules the Docker process to run.)

```
with open(data_txt, "a") as f:
    subprocess.run(["docker", "stats", "--format", "{{.MemUsage}}", "--no-stream"], stdout=f)
```